# Getting the count of resultset along with result rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL query for which I needed to have result rows count and results as the output of query.

For example,

```
SELECT count(*) total, id, name, age, grade
FROM Employee
where grade = 10;
```

It prints **only one row** with total count.
Please let me know what could be missing in query.

With GROUP BY:

Table:

```
id  name    age grade
1   ABC     30  10
2   DEF     31  10
3   GHI     29  6
4   PQR     29  10
```

Query:

```
SELECT count(*) total, id, name, age, grade
FROM Employee
where grade = 10
group by id, name, age, grade

total   id  name    age grade
1      1    ABC     30  10
1      2    DEF     31  10
1      4    PQR     29  10
```

Under total, I expect to have 3 as the value although it will be repeated. 
Here my intention is to have total row count and result rows as part of single query.

Comment: Invalid SQL statement. Don't mix aggregate functions and simple column references without a GROUP BY.

Comment: it is SQlite for small devices.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `GROUP BY` is what you want?

```
SELECT count(*) total, id, name, age, grade
FROM Employee
where grade = 10
group by id, name, age, grade
```

Comment: thanks... this will give count as 1 per row... but my intention is to have total rows count and result rows as part of the SQL query result. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you add sample table data and wanted result to your question? (So we don't have to guess...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE grade = 10)

    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT id, name, age, grade
    FROM Employee
    where grade = 10))
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL; JOIN is allowed only in the FROM clause.

Comment: Try again. There were not some parantheses

Comment: This still is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite computes result rows on the fly, so it does not know the size of the result set until you have fetched the last row.

If possible, change your program so that it just can count the rows.

If you really want to have the row count in every row, you have to compute it separately:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Employee
        WHERE grade = 10
       ) AS total,
       id, name, age, grade
FROM Employee
WHERE grade = 10;
```